# Partial Relaxation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, solver

In the context of a larger optimization problem I realized that I am missing the skill to implement/exploit the following observation:

In the problem I was faced with two related sets of indicator variables which contributed to the objective function through two separate terms. I obtained very weak root relaxation bounds (only considered one part of the objective function) and correspondingly long solution times (Gurobi). While this slow approach eventually worked out I kept wondering how to do it better the next time:

When I manually relaxed the set of binary variables related to the part that was properly captured and retained the formulation the problem very quickly solved yielding a very strong LB - but of course just including the LB value does not help. So here comes the question: How to "suggest" such a partial relaxation scheme to the solver? Is there a modeling technique that achieves this or am I missing a feature/parameter? I first thought about lazy handling of integrality but could not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is very close to the idea proposed by [Yang et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221712002731) for the single source capacitated facility location problem (SS-CFLP). They relax the allocation/assignment variables to be continuous which leads to a CFLP as a relaxation of the SS-CFLP. This is what they call a *partial relaxation* as the location variables are still kept as binary.

They then embed this relaxation into the so called [cut and solve](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370206000233) framework (Climer and Zhang, 2006) which alternates between solving a relaxation with some additional "piercing cuts" called *the dense problem* generating a lower bound, and a *sparse problem* with many variables fixed from which upper bounds are generated.